# Conversion methods: from_xxx() or to_xxx(), is there a reason I shouldn't stick with to_xxx()?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, python, constructors, type-conversion

I have a C++ library that I'm converting to Python.  In the C++ library I have multiple constructors and many different types of conversion functions (think radians to degrees, and different types of coordinate systems). In retrospect, these methods and constructors were rather ad-hoc, and, now after converting these things to python, I'm unsure about both APIs.

Creating *from* and *to* methods feels rather tedious, and now that I think of it, having the following:

```
auto geographic = Geographic(geodetic);
```

It isn't that much different from:

```
auto geographic = geodetic.to_geographic();
```

There are some constructors that take additional arguments, like:

```
LatLonAlt(LatLon latlon, double alt);
```

But now that I see that I can instead have a method that can do the following:

```
auto lla = lat_lon.to_lla(alt);
```

In my python translation, because overloading is not possible with out manually fiddling with parameters, I started to notice this repetition of constructors and `to_methods` a lot more, especially with the equivalent constructors having to be translated to

```
@classmethod
from_xxx(cls, ...)
```

My intuition is to convert everything for *this* application to "to_methods", but I don't have concrete reasons why. In this use case, I don't care about arbitrary conversion from or to other peoples types (ie like a serialization library might want). All type conversions are known ahead of time.

- Is there any reason not to stick with *only* `to_methods`?
- Are there arguments to be made for using *only* `from_methods` (or constructor equivalents)?
- Are there downsides to not doing *both*?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any reason not to stick with only `to_xyz()`?

Yes. If you have some unit-less inputs, `to_xyz()` fails to mention which units are assumed. Was it radians, or degrees? Maybe something else entirely?

> Are there arguments to be made for using only from_methods (or constructor equivalents)?

Constructors can only defined in the target class, conversion operators in the source-class. `to_xyz()` are free functions. All of them are constructor-equivalents.

Together with `from_xyz()` as static functions in the destination-class, they already cover it all. An alternative to the latter is using tags for choosing the right constructor.

Constructor-equivalents are `to_xyz()` defined outside the class. Together with `from_xyz()`, they cover it all.

> Are there downsides to not doing both?

See above. Sometimes, the extra-info is needed to know what the source is.